# Connection of ESP32/ ESP8266 not recognized using MacBook Pro

Tags: usb, hardware

I’m trying to connect those devices, with no success. When I’m using Linux machine I find at ‘/dev/ttyUSB0’. From googling around I understand it is a Mac issue.

Appreciate any guidance

Comment: What are these devices?

Comment: https://makeradvisor.com/best-esp8266-wi-fi-development-board/

Comment: If you issue the command `system_profiler SPUSBDataType | more` are you seeing the device anywhere?  (It's a long bit of output, so you'll have to search)

Comment: Not having one of these devices, I do know that USB serial ports show up as `cu.XXXXXXX`.  Do you see any of those devices?

Comment: you are right- when I connect Arduino - I find serial port with that prefix, but  not when ESP boards are connected

Comment: Have you installed the UART to USB drivers for the board if necessary? Also, can you confirm exactly which board it is that you have, I.e. NodeMCU, Wemos etc...

Comment: there sre no drivers needed as far as i know ( not needed when in linux )

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/NodeMCU-V3-1-ESP8266-ESP-12-E-Lua-CH340-WiFI-WLan-IoT-32-Bit-microUSB-Arduino/162472635911?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/ESP-32S-ESP32-NodeMCU-Development-Board-2-4GHz-WIFI-Bluetooth-Dual-Mode/272656534488?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Comment: I'm fairly sure you will need a USB to UART driver as I said. This is because unlike many Arduino boards, these sort of development boards do not have a built in usb to usb interface. Have a look at this video: https://youtu.be/G6CqvhXpBKM Also, double check you are using a data-capable USB cable. Best

Comment: @Tom - when connecting to Ubuntu it is with ordinary USB to microUSB cable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. There are a series of questions you need to go through that might change your solution.

1st of all, which board are you using? There are several versions of the ESP chip, which are well documented in the [arduino-esp8266 docs](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/2.5.0/boards.html)

2nd of all, I've read some forums that say that the USB cable has to be good quality, otherwise the board will not successfully connect. I don't know too much about good usb cables, but I do know that the shorter the better as far as signal loss is concerned

Lastly, which driver did you install? I installed the [SiliconLabs driver](https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers). It's important to note that in their readme (something I neglected to read until after 5 hours of troubleshooting) it explains that Mac blocks the driver from running until you give it permission. So, when you install the driver, the installer will need to get permission to run, but ALSO the driver itself will need to get permission to run. So, once you install the driver, go to System Preferences -> Security and allow the driver to run.

[image: system preferences]

I found out that you can verify that the driver was installed, you can run `kextstat` in the command line to list out all of the "kernel extensions," including the driver, that are installed on your mac.

These steps should help you get your board to show up in `/dev/tty.*` and also in the ports menu in your Arduino IDE. Or at the very least, these steps should help you debug at which step of the setup process something went wrong.

Once you see your board in the ports menu, don't forget that in order to upload code, you need to set the board to flash mode (I forget to do that a lot).

Comment: USB cable seems very important. Just changing that solved it for me on MBP.

Comment: The USB cable fix is just great !

Comment: Lol, same, USB cable, and it's ridiculous))

Answer (score 2):

Seriously. After changing my USB cable it worked.
first I was connecting ESP with a cable that came with the power bank. But when I changed it with my phone USB it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use the updated driver for newer MacOS versions (High Sierra in my case)

[Newer MacOS versions driver](https://kig.re/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html#sierra)

Answer (score 0):

For those like myself who stumble across this question running Sonoma 14.2.1 or newer:

I installed the SiliconLabs driver a long time ago. Now it appears that MacOS has the driver built in and the SiliconLabs driver conflicts with the built-in one, resulting in a "resource busy" error message when trying to connect, e.g. `sudo minicom /dev/tty.usb-serial-0001`.

The tell-tale is the presence of the additional terminal `/dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART`.

Running kextstat shows the SiliconLabs driver at the bottom.

As a temporary measure, you can disable it with `sudo kextunload /Library/Extensions/SiLabsUSBDriver.kext/`.

Answer (score -3):

I am using a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports with 2.3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5). I struggled a lot as I was not able to see a port for ESP32. Finally, I stumbled upon this youtube video and voila:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyocdvAKo64

I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.